# condense multiple instances into one

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

i've got a little code in in my main.js file that i've been using for activating various popover [bootstrap] buttons throughout the page.

```
// popover 1
var $btn1 = $('#btn1');
$btn1.data('state', 'hover');

var enterShow = function () {
    if ($btn1.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn1.popover('show');
    }
};
var exitHide = function () {
    if ($btn1.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn1.popover('hide');
    }
};

var clickToggle = function () {
    if ($btn1.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn1.data('state', 'pinned');
    } else {
        $btn1.data('state', 'hover')
        $btn.popover('hover');
    }
};

$btn1.popover({trigger: 'manual'})
    .on('mouseenter', enterShow)
    .on('mouseleave', exitHide)
    .on('click', clickToggle);


// popover 2
var $btn2 = $('#btn2');
$btn2.data('state', 'hover');

var enterShow = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.popover('show');
    }
};
var exitHide = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.popover('hide');
    }
};

var clickToggle = function () {
    if ($btn2.data('state') === 'hover') {
        $btn2.data('state', 'pinned');
    } else {
        $btn2.data('state', 'hover')
        $btn.popover('hover');
    }
};

$btn2.popover({trigger: 'manual'})
    .on('mouseenter', enterShow)
    .on('mouseleave', exitHide)
    .on('click', clickToggle);
```

but the more buttons (popovers) i add, the more instances of this i have to keep putting in the main.js.

QUESTION:
is there a multiplier i can use to achieve this result with just one instance of the code instead of an instance for each popover.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear to me but if you just want to make the same initialisation on differents buttons, then just create a function for it.

```
function initPopover(selector){
    var $btn1 = $(selector);
    $btn1.data('state', 'hover');

    var enterShow = function () {
        if ($btn1.data('state') === 'hover') {
            $btn1.popover('show');
        }
    };
    var exitHide = function () {
        if ($btn1.data('state') === 'hover') {
            $btn1.popover('hide');
        }
    };

    var clickToggle = function () {
        if ($btn1.data('state') === 'hover') {
            $btn1.data('state', 'pinned');
        } else {
            $btn1.data('state', 'hover')
            $btn.popover('hover');
        }
    };

    $btn1.popover({trigger: 'manual'})
        .on('mouseenter', enterShow)
        .on('mouseleave', exitHide)
        .on('click', clickToggle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixed variable name inside the event handler, use `$(this)`, which references the element the handler is bound to:

```
$('#btn1 #btn2') // <- note that I'm selecting both buttons
  .data('state', 'hover')
  .popover({trigger: 'manual'})
  .on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      if ($(this).data('state') === 'hover') {
        $(this).popover('show');
      }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      if ($(this).data('state') === 'hover') {
        $(this).popover('hide');
      }
    },
    click: function () {
      if ($(this).data('state') === 'hover') {
        $(this).data('state', 'pinned');
      } else {
        $(this).data('state', 'hover')
        $(this).popover('hover');
      }
    }
  });
```

I recommend to [read the **jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/) to learn more about event handlers, where it says:

> In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the keyword `this`. To turn the DOM element into a jQuery object that we can use jQuery methods on, we simply do `$( this )` [...]